# Loading images to TImageList and Reading them?

Tags: delphi

I am trying to load jpg into an imagelist by converting the .jpg to a bmp and then saving it to imagelist1.

From top to bottom of the code snip.
The Selectdir works and fileexists parts work. This is used to load in all the Images in a folder.All images are named like so 0.jpg / 1.jpg ect..

I then load the jpg to a tpicture. Set the bmp width /height and load the bmp with same image as jpg , i then add the bmp to the imagelist. And when its done it should show the first image 0.jpg

Two issues, first if i did it like so it would only show a small area (top left) of the bmp
but it was the correct image. I assume this is due to the option crop. which i cant seem to figure out how to make it select center during runtime?

Second, If i put

```
Imagelist1.width := currentimage.width;
Imagelist1.height := currentimage.height;
```

Then it shows last image. like     `Imagelist1.GetBitmap()` did not work?
so i assume a fix for either one would be great!
cheers
squills

```
procedure TForm1.Load1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
openDialog : TOpenDialog;
dir :string;
MyPicture :TPicture;
currentimage :Tbitmap;
image : integer;
clTrans : TColor;
begin
  Image := 0 ;
  //lets user select a dir
 SelectDirectory(Dir, [sdAllowCreate, sdPerformCreate, sdPrompt],SELDIRHELP);
  myPicture :=Tpicture.Create;
  currentimage := TBitmap.Create;
//keeps adding images as long as the file path exsist.
//thus comic pages should be renumbed to 0-XX
  while FileExists(Dir+'\'+inttostr(image)+'.jpg') do
  begin
   try
    MyPicture.LoadFromFile(Dir+'\'+inttostr(image)+'.jpg');   //load image to jpg holder
    currentimage.Width := mypicture.Width;       //set width same as jpg
    currentimage.Height:= mypicture.Height;      //set height same as jpg
    currentimage.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, myPicture.Graphic);     //draw jpg on bmp
    clTrans:=currentimage.TransparentColor;           //unknown if needed?
    //Imagelist1.Width := currentimage.Width;
    //imagelist1.Height := currentimage.Height;
    Imagelist1.Addmasked(Currentimage,clTrans);     //add to imagelist
   finally
    image := image +1;                          //add one so it adds next page
   end;
 end;
 ImageList1.GetBitmap(0,zImage1.Bitmap);
 mypicture.Free;
 currentimage.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding a lot of unnecessary overhead by using the `TImage` every time.

Try something like this (untested, because I don't have a folder full of images named this way - it compiles, though <g>). You'll need to add `Jpeg` to your implementation `uses` clause if it's not already there, of course.

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DirName: string;
begin
  DirName := 'D:\Images';
  if SelectDirectory('Select Image Path', 
                     'D:\TempFiles', 
                     DirName, 
                     [sdNewUI], 
                     Self) then
    LoadImages(DirName);
end;

procedure TForm2.LoadImages(const Dir: string);
var
  i: Integer;
  CurFileName: string;
  JpgIn: TJPEGImage;
  BmpOut: TBitmap;
begin
  i := 1;
  while True do
  begin
    CurFileName := Format('%s%d.jpg', 
                          [IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(Dir), i]);
    if not FileExists(CurFileName) then
      Break;
    JpgIn := TJPEGImage.Create;
    try
      JpgIn.LoadFromFile(CurFileName);

      // If you haven't initialized your ImageList width and height, it
      // defaults to 16 x 16; we can set it here, if all the images are
      // the same dimensions.
      if (ImageList1.Count = 0) then
        ImageList1.SetSize(JpgIn.Width, JpgIn.Height);

      BmpOut := TBitmap.Create;
      try
        BmpOut.Assign(JpgIn);
        ImageList1.Add(BmpOut, nil);
      finally
        BmpOut.Free;
      end;
    finally
      JpgIn.Free;
    end;
    Inc(i);
  end;
  if ImageList1.Count > 0 then
  begin
    BmpOut := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      ImageList1.GetBitmap(0, BmpOut);
      Image1.Picture.Assign(BmpOut);
    finally
      BmpOut.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: this does work, to a point, once its done loading it does not show any image. also i had to change image1 to ZImage1.bitmap.assign(bmpout);   As ZImage1 is a class from TGraphicControl. not sure if this matters..

Comment: it seems to never get into the while loop. Always breaks out

Comment: There's no way (short of an exception you're ignoring) that it can't get into the `while` loop if the function is called; `while True` is always `True`. The only way that code wouldn't execute it is if `SelectDirectory` returns false and the function is not called as a result. What does the debugger show you if you set a breakpoint on that line?

Comment: Got it. `SelectDirectory` returns a pathname without the trailing backslash. (The debugger showed me that when you evaluate the parameter passed to `FileExists`, BTW.) Edited to fix. (Your really should learn to use the debugger - it's your friend. <g>)

Comment: ok fixed it was an format issue,  But now back to orginal problem, it only shows the top left corner of the image..

Comment: Just tested it, and it correctly displays the image. The issue is at your end, probably with the configuration of the `TImage` or `ZImage` or whatever you're using to display it. I can post a screen capture to prove the code works properly (including code to generate 10 24x24 JPG test images).

Comment: One afterthought: Have you properly set the `ImageList.Width` and `Height` before adding images to it? It defaults to 16 x 16. You can set it with your code if all the images are the same size; I've added that code above in the start of the `while` loop.

Comment: I am sure your right as it looks correct. At least i know that this part is right. But now on to the Zimage. But it just seems like the TImageList is the issue. cause if I load an image into the zimage1 properties (an image editor pops up) at non runtime. When it starts up the image is perfect. it seems to be a runtime only problem with Timagelist?. If you have any other idea's please suggest, if not ill keep pulling out hair..cheers

Comment: See my last comment (and edit) about the imagelist's dimensions. Can't help you with ZImage, as I don't have any idea what it is or how it's written, and that should be a separate question anyway. :-)

Comment: ok thanks for all hlep , issue seems to be wth my custiom zimage.paint i will make another question for that . as soon as i can think of how to word my question. answer accepted thanks for all help!

Comment: I had another question about this.. Can the size of the image be to large for Timagelist? 973 x 1518

Comment: That might be the issue. The images internally are stored as one wide image; if `Masked` is true, it actually creates two per image added. (See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), section "Creating and Destroying".) How many are you adding? Your design may be flawed - it you have many of that size, you're going to use a lot of memory.

Comment: We're getting way too close to a chat room here. You really should be making these types of things questions instead of asking here in comments. :-)