# Picture Database, TDBImages, TImageList, Delphi

Tags: image, delphi, jpeg, delphi-2010, timagelist

I am writing a programme that shows a picture(map). when you click on a part of the picture it must Zoom in. There are 26 pictures in total(Including main picture). I Want to load those pictures into Delphi and replace Image1(Whole_map.jpg) with Amusement_park.jpg.

I want to use the good quality jpg not bitmaps :(
*Is it possible to load those 26 images into TImageList and still use the images with its quality
or
*Can i save the images in some sort of Database and load it into Delphi

[Loading images and converting to bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988310/loading-images-to-timagelist-and-reading-them)
doesn't help because i don't want to use bitmaps.
I also don't want to use any 3rd party components because this program must run on default Delphi 2010.

Comment: Regarding the database part [Saving and loading jpeg images to database ....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214686/saving-and-loading-jpeg-images-to-database-not-working-delphi)

Comment: I'm not sure you should use `TImageList` in this case to store (hi-res?) images (not icons). create and use generic `TObjectList<TImage>` instead.

Comment: Why don't you siply create and array of TJpegImage and store individual images in each TJpegImage.

Comment: @SilverWarior I have created an array `arrPics : array[1..26] of TJPEGImage;`
how do I add the images to it? I have tried loading the location names(string) into the array but it ain't working.

Comment: Without you providing some code of how you did it, its hard to say why it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my coment you can create an array of TJPEGImage objects to store the images.

You do this like so:

```
//Global array for storing images
var Images: Array [1..26] of TJPEGImage;

implemenetation

...

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 1 to 26 do
  begin
    //Since TJPEGIMage is a class we first need to create each one as array only
    //stores pointer to TJPEGImage object and not the object itself
    Images[I] := TJPEGImage.Create;
    //Then we load Image data from file into each TJPEGImage object
    //If file names are not numerically ordered you would probably load images
    //later and not inside this loop. This depends on your design
    Images[I].LoadFromFile('D:\Image'+IntToStr(I)+'.jpg');
  end;
end;
```

As you see in source coments the array only stores pointers to TJPEGImage objects and not the TJPEGImage objects themself. So don't forget to create them before trying to load any image data to them. Failing to do so will result in Access Violation.

Also becouse you have created these TJPEGImage objects by yourself you also need to free them by yourself to avoid posible memory leaks

```
procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
var I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 1 to 26 do
  begin
    Images[I].Free;
  end;
end;
```

In order to show these stored images in your TImage component use this

```
//N is array index number telling us which array item stores the desired image
Image1.Picture.Assign(Images[N]);
```

**Second approach that you can use**

Now since TJPEGImage are classed objects you could also use TObjectList to store pointers to them.
In such case creation code would look like this

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var I: Integer;
    Image: TJPEGImage;
for I := 1 to NumberOfImages do
  begin
    //Create TObject list with AOwnsObjects set to True means that destroying
    //the object list will also destroy all of the objects it contains
    //NOTE: On ARC compiler destroying TObjectList will only remove the reference
    //to the objects and they will be destroyed only if thir reference count
    //drops to 0
    Images := TObjectList.Create(True);
    //Create a new TJPEGImage object
    Image := TJPEGImage.Create;
    //Load image data into it from file
    Image.LoadFromFile('Image'+IntToStr(I)+'.jpg');
    //Add image object to our TObject list to store reference to it for further use
    Images.Add(Image);
  end;
end;
```

You would now show these images like so

```
//Note becouse first item in TObject list has index of 0 you need to substract 1
//from your ImageNumber
Image1.Picture.Assign(TJPEGImage(Images[ImageNumber-1]));
```

Since we set TObjectList to own our TJPEGImage objects we can quickly destroy all of them like so

```
//NOTE: On ARC compiler destroying TObjectList will only remove the reference
//to the objects and they will be destroyed only if thir reference count
//drops to 0
Images.Free;
```

Comment: Thank a lot bro! I used the first approach and it works perfectly.
a bit of the topic... you said that I need to free it
    
`procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
var I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 1 to 26 do
  begin
    Images[I].Free;
  end;
end;`
    
i don't understand the effect that i has?

Comment: Won't be easy to explain this using coment/s due to their size limit but I'll try. First thing you need to realize the difference between components and regular classes (components are special classes). When you create a component you assign an owner to it during creation. So now when the owner is being destroeyd it notifies all components that it owns about this so they also destroy themselves (free their own memory). So in case of components you don't need to pay any special attention unles you set owner to lill (no owner) at their creation. It continues ...

Comment: But when you are creating other classes like TJPEGImage in your case you can't specify an owner to them which means that they won't be notified when they need to destroy themseves unles you do so by calling free for each of them. And that would mean that they will never free up the memory they are using. Such scenario is know as "memory leak". Now it is true that in your specific case not freeing up the TJPEGImage objects wouldn't cause much problem becouse their memory would be free up at application termination. It continues again ...

Comment: But if those were some other classes who handle their memory differently it could result in some memory not being freed even on application termination. And this is bad becouse it could lead toyour OS running out of memory as OS still consideres that part of memory to be reserved. Now there could be even more serious problems if those classes are initiating handles to soem files on hard drive as OS might still treat such file as still being opene even after your application termination. It continues again ...

Comment: Or if those classes provide some extencded functionality that is used by some other application terminating yours would probably result in hanging the other. Why? Becouse those classes won't be destroyed they won't have a chance to notify the other application about the fact that they won't be able to work any more. So that other application would probably be just waiting for some result indefinitly and thus hang. Anywhay there are to many cases to write all of them down here. It continues again ...

Comment: Anywhay it is good practice that you free up any dynamically created class as soon as you finish work with them. Oh almost forgot. As I said in your case not freeing those TJPEGImage objects probably wouldn't cause any problems since you use them until the application is terinated. But if you would use similar approach for loading up the images for your second from closing that form would result in that memory of still being in use. And creating the second from again would not reuse existing memory but reserve even more. That could be seen in your application memory usage to continuosly grow.

Comment: I recomend you learn more about dynamic class and component creation. You can use this as basic reference: http://delphi.about.com/od/kbcurt/a/dynamiccreation.htm Also do learn some more about memory leaks: http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2006/qt/memory_leak.htm I would also recomend you learn about making your own classes. Now you may think: "Why would I do that? I have no need to make new calsses." Learning about this will alow you to better understand how existing classes works (when is memory reserved, what all can be done in destructors which are called after you call free etc.)

Comment: Learning about creating my own classes gave me a much better understanding of all components and classes that I had been using before that. And it game me a compleetly different view about aproaching of certain problems. So it was defeinitly worth it.